# Remover JPanel da exibição

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Gostaria de saber como remover um `JPanel` que está dentro de uma `JFrame`.

Eu não quero usar as informações nem nada, só quero que ele feche.

Usar `setVisible(false)` deixa o panel invisível, eu não quero isso, quero apenas que ele feche.

Procurei na internet mas também não consegui muito sucess, como fazer isso?

Código do JFrame:

```
    public class MenuAultima extends JFrame { 
    public MenuAultima() {
        add(new Fundo());
        setTitle("A última esperança");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(800,625);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main (String[]args){
        new MenuAultima();
    }
}
```

Código do JPanel:

```
    public class Fundo extends JPanel  implements MouseListener{
    private Image fundo; 
    private Image novojogo;
    private Image comojogar;
    private Image  sair;
    public Fundo() {
        setFocusable(true);
        addMouseListener(this);
        ImageIcon Menu = new ImageIcon ("Imagens-menu\\menu.fw.png");
        fundo = Menu.getImage();
        ImageIcon botao = new ImageIcon ("Imagens-menu\\novojogo.fw.png");
        novojogo = botao.getImage();
        ImageIcon botaodois = new ImageIcon ("Imagens-menu\\comojogar.fw.png");
        comojogar = botaodois.getImage();
        ImageIcon botaotres = new ImageIcon ("Imagens-menu\\sair.fw.png");
        sair = botaotres.getImage();
    }
    public void paint (Graphics g){
        Graphics2D graficos = (Graphics2D) g;
        graficos.drawImage(fundo, 0, 0, null);
        graficos.drawImage(novojogo, 511, 346, null);
        graficos.drawImage(comojogar, 498, 410, null);
        graficos.drawImage(sair, 561 , 469 , null);
    }
    public Rectangle getBotaoComoJogar(){
        return new Rectangle(498, 410, comojogar.getWidth(null), comojogar.getHeight(null));
    }
    public String coords(MouseEvent e){
        return e.getX() + ", " + e.getY();
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        Rectangle BotaoComoJogar = getBotaoComoJogar();
        if (BotaoComoJogar.contains(getMousePosition())){

            //Coisas acontecem aqui

        }
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){

    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){

    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){

    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){

    }
}
```

Ali onde existe o comentário eu gostaria de colocar uma ação onde o JPanel Fundo fosse fechado e outro JPanel por exemplo, como jogar, fosse aberto.

Comment: Adicione o código do seu jpanel, `setvisible()` já atende ao que você quer, não tem outro jeito de esconder um componente, mas o espaço que ele ocupa não vai sumir.

Comment: @DiegoF Isso faz com que ele fique invisível, mas não fecha. Isso vai trazer problemas no meu código futuramente. Não há mesmo outro jeito?

Comment: Não existe uma função de .dispose()? Já tentou procurar algo mais direcionado para isso? Talvez atenda o que você precisa.

Comment: @LeonardoCoelho dispose é para containers top-level, como jframe, jpanel não possui dispose.

Comment: Gregory você pode remover o componente, usando `seuFrame.remove(seuJPanel)`. Fora isso, não vejo outra maneira menos trabalhosa de fazer o que você quer.

Comment: @DiegoF Sim, estava tentando usar isso, mas assim: Existe um botão dentro do meu JPanel que deve fazer com que ele feche e abra outro JPanel, entende?

Comment: Seria interessante você adicionar o código na pergunta e editá-la, explicando melhor como funciona sua aplicação, o que você quer fazer e que não consegue. Assim fica até mais fácil de responder.

Comment: Editado. Expliquei certinho o que quero que aconteça ali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como seu `JPanel` é uma classe a parte, será necessário você recuperar o `JFrame` nela, para depois poder adicionar o novo painel e remover o atual. Não considero isso uma boa prática, pois entendo que estamos delegando funções a classe do `JPanel` que deveriam ser de responsabilidade do `JFrame`.

De todo jeito, adaptando ao seu código, ficaria assim:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    Rectangle BotaoComoJogar = getBotaoComoJogar();
    if (BotaoComoJogar.contains(getMousePosition())){
        JFrame janelaPrincipal = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        janelaPrincipal.remove(this);
        janelaPrincipal.add(new OutroJPanel());
        janelaPrincipal.revalidade();
    }
}
```

O método [`SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor-java.awt.Component-) irá recuperar o `JFrame` onde você inseriu o painel(o painel deve ser passado como argumento, por isso usei o `this`). Atente-se que, se o painel for adicionado a outro, essa linha irá dar erro de cast, pois como pode ser visto na documentação, este método retorna a janela somente se o componente passado foi adicionado a uma. Se ele se encontra dentro de outro painel, o método retornará nulo.

O método `revalidade()` é quem vai notificar a janela de que houve alterações e que ela deverá ser redesenhada.

Comment: Sei que não é uma boa prática, mas ainda estou aprendendo Java.. Com erros se aprende! Obrigado! Irei discutir mais afundo com meu professor, foi só esta questão que ele não conseguiu me ajudar.