# Abrir Painel através de um JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

Preciso de saber como faço um `JMenuItem` abrir uma `JPanel`, ou seja, ao clicar no `JMenuItem`, abrir o JPanel correspondente, isto em Eclipse, através do windowBuilder.

Esta é a imagem da minha tela com o menu:

[!Imagem da tela com o menu[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axfBO.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axfBO.jpg)

Código da chamada do JPanel:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
       try {
        Agenda1 window = new Agenda1();
        window.frame.setVisible(true);
       } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
     });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Agenda1() {
     initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
      frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));
      -- -- -

      JPanel panelEditar = new JPanel();
      frame.getContentPane().add(panelEditar, "name_5905325036674");
      panelEditar.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));
      -- -- --

      JMenuItem mntmEditar = new JMenuItem("Editar");
      mntmEditar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        CardLayout card = (CardLayout) frame.getContentPane().getLayout();
        card.show(frame.getContentPane(), "panelEditar");

       }


      });
```

O código completo aqui: http://pastebin.com/6rn7sSG6

Comment: Como você está construindo sua janela? O jpanel vai abrir onde? Pra ficar mais facil ajudar, edite a pergunta e adicione um [mcve] , porque assim está muito ampla.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/69bpmqibd/  quero que o botão editar lá em cima abra  o panelEditar - diz-me se precisares de mais dados

Comment: Adicione na pergunta, com código também, fica dificil simular um problema por imagem.

Comment: Rui, **adicione na pergunta**, clicando em [edit]. Aqui nos comentários fica embolado. Adicione tanto a imagem, quanto ao código e formate o código selecionando-o e clicando em `{}`

Comment: Você quer trocar o painel em exibição para o panelEditar ?

Comment: sim clicando em Editar(jmenuitem)

Comment: Que painel você quer adicionar? o panelEditar já foi adicionado. Sua pergunta está confusa demais. Edite-a explicando melhor, com um código mais de acordo com sua duvida.

Comment: eu não quero adicionar nenhum panel. Eu quero que ao executar o programa o utilizador clique em evento -> editar e abra o panelEditar, na imagem está a mostrar outro panel, e quando eu executo não consigo mudar para outra ''página'' ou panel, se puderes ajudar agradeço

Comment: Então o problema não está nesse código. Nele você já está exibindo o painel. Edite a pergunta e adicione um codigo mais de acordo com seu problema.

Comment: Pois eu também achava que esta parte do código está bem feita.... não sei em que outra parte é que possa estar mal... não consigo arranjar nenhum exemplo em que alguém faça isto para ver o que tenho de mudar... e o meu codigo tem 300 linhas não sei que te mostre mais...

Comment: Pra trocar o painel exibido, veja o código [dessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120958/28595)

Comment: será que o erro está na parte que meti agora?

Comment: Qual painel é exibido ao abrir a janela?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/qy1yzgoc9/

Comment: Tente `panelEditar.setVisible(true)` dentro do `ActionListener`

Comment: não resultou :(

Comment: Rui, veja se resolve a resposta abaixo.

Comment: não resolveu :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está aqui:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panelEditar, "name_5905325036674");
```

O nome que você está dando pro seu painel é `name_5905325036674`, e nao `painelEditar`.

Ou você altera o nome na linha acima, ou alterna no `ActionListener`, com o nome já informado:

```
card.show(frame.getContentPane(), "name_5905325036674");
```

**Referência:**

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4112/28595

Comment: já o fiz e continua a não dar

Comment: @RuiMendes não tem como eu simular se o problema está em outro lugar se você não adicionar um [mcve]. Tente adicionar um pedaço de código que seja possivel simular seu código, para verificar onde está problema.

Comment: https://www.zipshare.com/download/eyJhcmNoaXZlSWQiOiJhM2JlZDBhMS1iZTg0LTQ2NzYtYTk0OC1hYjQwNzhiZjE2MTEifQ==

link para dowload do codigo todo... tambem não é grande... estou neste problema desde ontem

Comment: @RuiMendes poste o código todo no pastebin ou outro site de código.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6rn7sSG6 - ja esta, não conhecia o site :p

Comment: @RuiMendes não há problema algum com seu código. O que acontece é que o `panelEditar` foi iniciado mas você não fez mais nada com ele, não tem elemento nenhum. Adicione um componente nele pra você ver que está funcionando conforme a resposta lhe indicou.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ASrD2Z83 adicionei um button ao panelEditar, não resolveu, para alem de que pelo meio me apareceu o seguinte erro:http://postimg.org/image/6tooa64q7/

Comment: @RuiMendes como eu já disse, **não tem problema algum com seu código**. Executou normalmente aqui com o editar sendo trocado.

Comment: então como é que eu não consigo executar :( nas aulas dava para mudar entre panels com o interface a correr atraves do menubar, aqui não consigo

Comment: Faça o seguinte,  crie uma nova classe vazia no seu projeto, copie todo o código dessa do pastebin e coloque nela(cuidado com o nome diferente de classes), e execute apenas essa nova classe, não o projeto. Verá que funciona.

Comment: voilá - é comum acontecer isto de ter de criar outra página? muito obrigado pela paciência e tudo mais :)

Comment: @RuiMendes pode ser problema com sua IDE. Fale com seu professor sobre este problema, talvez ele lhe ajude a arrumar algum problema de configuração.

Comment: pois.... ele so responde durante a semana XD agr vou alterando entre estes 2 projectos o codigo ate o programa estar completo - obrigado @Diego F

Comment: @RuiMendes Seria interessante marcar a respostas como aceita clicando no `v` para que sirva de referencia para outros com duvida semelhante, afinal, um dos problemas que iria impedir de abrir o painel é o da resposta :)

Comment: 1º dia :p da desconto